# How to automatically arrange the code structure?

Tags: delphi, code-structure

I have observed that components has a uniform, neat and well arrange code structure. was it automatically arranged or manual?

is there a way to make it automatic? like Code Completion in Delphi?

I am using Delphi 7, 2009, 2010 XE

Comment: Could you tag your version of Delphi, please ? It might be important. With that *arranged* you mean formatted, so the next question is how. Same indentation, the order of procedures, fields etc. About the Code Completion you've mentioned, try to press `CTRL + J` in your code editor and type `class` for instance and press `ENTER`. It will produce you the class skeleton by the template. But personally I would be very happy if someone answer here something in the meaning of *hey, use this tool, it will format your code exactly as the Delphi RTL is*

Comment: Its still vague, because "code structure" is really differs from the formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the "code structure" which you observe is based usually on the [Delphi Language Style Guide](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=Style_Guide). Also, you can use a [delphi code formatter](http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/) to get similar results. The newer versions of delphi include a [source formatter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Formatting_Source_Code) built in to the IDE.

Comment: the newer versions = since Delphi 2010